# All possible outcomes of numbers and letters (a-z 0-99)

Tags: python, random, generator

**Python :)**

Can anyone help me code this? I cannot find an example anywhere! Its a combination so it will list all possible outcomes like this.

Numbers- 1-9 all possible outcomes is 11,22,33,44,45,59,15 ext.

I need a script for python that can do this with these numbers. 0-99 and a-z so an example of one output could be AA. OR (A1)

```
1806GA00CXM8
---------^^-
```

Now I need these two letters and numbers to be replaced with one of the selected combinations. As my example was AA here is what it should look like.

```
1806GA00CAA8
---------^^-
```

This should loop until it does all the combinations

Ending with,

> 1806GA00C**99**8

Halfway should look like something like this

> 1806GA00C**N5**8     (A mixture of numbers of letters)

Outputs to `combo.txt`

Hopefully, you get this I have tried my self but have got no result.

***Summary*** 
1)Make a list of possible combinations 0-99 and a-z.
2)Replace the 2 letters/numbers in the text with the combination. 
3)Repeat until it has put all the possible outputs in.
4)Outputs as .txt

txt should look like this after opening.

> 1806GA00C**AA**8
>   1806GA00C**AB**8
>   1806GA00C**AC**8
>   ...
>   1806GA00C**5N**8
>   1806GA00C**5M**8
>   ...
>   1806GA00C**ZX**8
>   1806GA00C**ZZ**8

Thanks so much!

Comment: @arieljuod I am stuck on the making a list of possible combinations 0-99 and a-z. I have looked around and cannot find any help.

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
from itertools import product

numbers = [str(i) for i in range(10)]
letters = [chr(i) for i in range(65, 91)]
sigma = numbers + letters

for word in product(sigma, repeat=2):
  print('1806GA00C' + ''.join(word) + '8')
```